# Different cases for the same (or maybe not really) 'if' condition

Tags: javascript

I was recently passing JS test and one interesting thing i saw is that the 2 statements:

```
if( x <= 100 ) {...}

if( !(x > 100) ) {...}
```

Are not the same. In the way, that there are special values existing that'll trigger only one of the following statements.

The question is **why** and what are those **values**?

Comment: Everything that casts to `NaN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look for edges cases like:

```js
let x = undefined;

if( x <= 100 ){
   console.log("case one")
}

if( !(x > 100) ) {
  console.log("case two")
}
```

or

```js
let x = "Foo bar";

if( x <= 100 ){
   console.log("case one")
}

if( !(x > 100) ) {
  console.log("case two")
}
```

or

```js
 let x = NaN

    if( x <= 100 ){
       console.log("case one")
    }

    if( !(x > 100) ) {
      console.log("case two")
    }
```